# how to enter free-form text in cell with drop-down-list?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I'm having to do a little bit of user data validation in Excel which will be used for application upload.  I have a list of values (LOVs) that I'm providing in a drop down box in an Excel.  That's easy.

**Is there a way to also allow for free form text in the drop down list cell?**  Excel tries to validate it against the given LOVs.  I don't need the user-entered text to become part of that LOV, just that it is possible to 'override' or put additional text in there instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the Validation dialog, go to the "Error Alert" tab and uncheck "Show error alert after invalid data is entered".